# How can I log a prepared statement in ADO.Net / MySQL Connector

Tags: c#, mysql, logging, ado.net, mysql-connector

I'd like to use prepared statements with MySQL Connector/NET (or any ADO.Net provider for that matter) for our database access.

The problem is that we need to log the full SQL statements as they would be sent to the server if we weren't using prepared statements.

Is there any way we can do this?